# Detecting rotated width/height of UIView after orientation change

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I would like to be able to inspect a UIView instance that may or may not have been rotated from its original orientation (by the user rotating the device for instance) and determine what the "true" width and height are. "true" here meaning, if a view on a portrait-oriented iPad was 768x1024 before rotation, after being turned sideways I would calculate that the new width was 1024 and the new height was 768.

It appears that if I apply the view's transform to its frame property like this:

```
CGRect rotated = CGRectApplyAffineTransform([myview frame], [myview transform);
```

I get the desired result. Apple's documentation however states that UIView::frame is undefined if the transform for the view is not the identity transform, so maybe it's not a good idea to rely on this calculation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`view.bounds` will return the rect you want

`view.frame` will return a rect with the transfrom  applied to the bounds along with position.

Comment: Bounds doesn't help if you are also transforming Scale. It will read the rect of the untransformed UIview

Answer (score -1):

Well due to lack of input, I'm going to go with my solution of using:

`CGRect rotated = CGRectApplyAffineTransform([myview frame], [myview transform);`

To get the properly oriented bounding. If somebody has another solution or can confirm this is safe I will award the answer to them instead.